# Problem linking WLAN to Ethernet

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, network-bridge

So I've been trying to use a laptop who's wifi card doesn't work properly, by using a Lenovo V570 laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 to bridge the two networks. I changed my ethernet network to "Shared to other computers" through Network Manager, but it still refuses to work.

I believe the issue may be in my /etc/network/interfaces, as I did edit it at one point and forgot to make a backup. Here is what mine currently consists of:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

If someone could post their (stock) /etc/network/interfaces file, I could try with that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is the interfaces file default content. The other interfaces are managed by NetworkManager.

Comment: So my /etc/network/interfaces is as it should be. Any other ideas why the networks aren't bridging?